# Android End All Other Activities?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I am having an issue at the moment and would appriciate another persons fresh view on the problem.

I have 3 separate activities.

> Home
>
> Question
>
> Answer

From Home you can only go to Question from Question you can go to Answer. Now from Answer you can pull up the menu and go back to the Home screen. At this point it ends the Question via a callback and Answer via finish(), but the very first home screen activity is still there and if you click the back button it will go back to the same screen again.

This means if I opened a question from the home screen then went to answer and from the menu went to the home screen. If I did this a few times there would be 2, 3 or more home screens running.

Is there something I can run to remove all other activities from my running app?

Sorry if that's a little confusing, my head hurts just thinking about this too. If you want a clearer clarification of this I will try my best.

Comment: you'll probably want to look into adding flags to your intents upon starting each activity.  see http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#addFlags(int)

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP

Comment: You can also add flags to the manifest. I suggest looking into singleInstance and SingleTask (I think they're called)

Comment: @Falmarri that worked perfectly. If you want to submit it as an answer I shall accept it

Answer (score 0):

Before you `finish()` the Answer, set a flag of some sort (global var, shared pref, your choice) to notify the Question to also call `finish()`.  This will back you into the Home screen in a clean manner.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop more than one instance of an activity being started using the intent's flags, e.g

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, ActivityA.class); 
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT); startActivity(i);
```

see: [public Intent setFlags (int flags)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setFlags%28int%29)